# How can i repeat the a image vertically alone?

Tags: android, xml, repeat

I am trying to repeat with xml file and it was good with regular background and also for the curved edged buttons etc. Now i am trying to have a outlined background for a layout with repeat xml.

How can i repeat only in Xaxis or Yaxis with a piece.

The final thing i required and the slices i have are:
[image: corner1]

[image: corner2]

[image: vertical piece]

[image: final]

Comment: use draw9patch for this image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Got the solution and i have used this XML file in drawable and it added as the layout background.

[shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

```
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#9B9A9A"/>

<padding android:left="2dp"
         android:top="2dp"
         android:right="2dp"
         android:bottom="2dp"/> 

<corners 
    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

// if you have the PSD file make this image as mush as small and make it as a draw9patch image

so that it will automatically fits to your requirement

[image]